# Perform operation on two columns of table to get value for third

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am making a c# desktop application to calculate total salary of employees and than generate a report.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emplyees] (
    [id]           INT          NOT NULL,
    [Name]         VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [State]        VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Salary]       FLOAT (53)   NULL,
    [Tax]          FLOAT (53)   NULL,
    [Total_Salary] FLOAT (53)   NULL
);
```

system should calculate total_salary which is  [salary] - [tax].
how can i calculate total_salary
Using visual studio 2013 , sql server express 2012 and sql management studio 2012.

Comment: Well, good luck with that. Do you have a question in there? I didn't see one. btw, don't use float, use either numeric or money data types.

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you create an SQL query that does it? If not - then that is what your question should be about, not about VS, SQL express and C#, though take into account that such questions have been already asked and answered a million times, so you actually don't even need to ask a new question.

Comment: You should be storing money in columns with the [`MONEY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx) type or [`DECIMAL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) type. They provide an exact numbers with fixed precision and scale. `FLOAT` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not select the sum in the SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT id, 
       Name, 
       State, 
       Salary, 
       Tax, 
       Salary - Tax AS Total_Salary
FROM   employees
```

No need to actually store it in the table. It is redundant information.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use **computed column**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emplyees] (
[id]           INT          NOT NULL,
[Name]         VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[State]        VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Salary]       FLOAT (53)   NULL,
[Tax]          FLOAT (53)   NULL,
[Total_Salary] AS [Salary]-[Tax]
);
```